# Laptop DVD-RW Drive disc detection loop

Tags: laptop, dvd

An NEC Versa L1100 has a DVD-RW drive.  The drives reads CDs perfectly well, but when a DVD is inserted, the drive make a series of disc reading noises, and cycles through the same set of noises every 3 seconds.  These noises never cease, as if the drive isn't properly recognising the disc.

However, if I use a program to browse the disc, like Windows Explorer, or Windows Media Player, most of the time (with the same disc) I can browse the disc contents.

Are there some settings, like disc preview or disc read settings I can adjust to prevent this (annoyingly useless :P ) cycle from occuring?

Comment: Is it only one DVD, or have you tried multiple of them? Burned DVD's or store-bought? Is the Windows Event Log showing any warnings or errors related to the drive?  Is AutoPlay enabled?

Comment: Any DVD.  Store-bought.  Error Log says: "An error was detected on device \Device\CdRom0 during a paging operation.", "The driver detected a controller error on \Device\CdRom0.", "The device, \Device\Ide\IdePort0, did not respond within the timeout period."  Autoplay is set to prompt me to choose which action.